# Processing objects of different classes in Python in parallel

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have 6 different classes.

In main, I am creating one object of each class.

I want to call `eachObject.processFiles()` of each object parallely.

The processFiles method processes the object files by reading them, manipulates the data, and save it in persistent object. Each processFiles call takes around 5 minutes. If it is done sequentially then main is taking around 30 min.

I am right now doing it sequentially, but I want to speed up the 6 objects' processing their files in minimum cpu time. All objects are independent of each other, and I think multithreaded way would be efficient. But I haven't done multi threading any before. So wanted to know if it would be safe to do that, and how to do that. A code snippet would help.

How can I do it in parallel?

```
class system(object):
  def __init__(self, leNameList):
    self.files = fileNameList

  def processFiles(self):
    self.feeds= self.readFiles()
    self.processFeeds()

class A(system):
  def processFeeds(self):
    """ process the feed 
         in A way """

class B(system):
  def processFeeds(self):
    """ process the feed 
         in B way """

def main():
  aObj = A(fileList)
  bObj = B(fileList2)
  aObj.processFiles()
  bObj.processFiles()
```

Comment: Plz edit your question. The commend is too unstructured for reading

Comment: It is impossible to say without knowing what your bottlenecks are. Also it might be easier to slice differently: instead of doing (A on all files), (B on all files), etc, can you do (A, B, etc) on each file? This might help by only loading each file once.

Comment: no, you want to process the files in **maximum** cpu time, and minimum **wall** time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

```
import multiprocessing

class system(object):
  def __init__(self, fileNameList):
    self.files = fileNameList

  def processFiles(self):
    # self.feeds= self.readFiles()
    return self.processFeeds()

class A(system):
  def processFeeds(self):
    return ["A feed", "example data"] + self.files

class B(system):
  def processFeeds(self):
    return ["B feed", "hello world"] + self.files

def process_file_task(processor):
    return processor.processFiles()

def main():
  aObj = A(["a"])
  bObj = B(["b"])
  data = multiprocessing.Pool().map(process_file_task, [aObj, bObj])
  print(data)
```

Here I've populated your code with example data, so that you can test drive this solution out of the box, but the gist of it is:

- Instead of altering global variables or object state, return the data you generate.
- Use `multiprocessing.Pool().map` to execute the functions in different processes and return each result in order.

The drawback to this is that `multiprocessing` can be a bit finicky to work with at times, and you have to ensure that everything passing process boundaries can be pickled.

---

One more thing to check in your code is the file lists. If they have a lot of files in common, you should separate the process of file reading out and ensure that the same file doesn't have to be read twice.